# Installing a driver from a Github project - Robotic Arm

Tags: drivers, compiling

I am new to Linux so i'm sorry if this is obvious.

I have built a robotic arm (http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/usb-controlled-robotic-arm-kit-a37jn) and would like to get it working under the linux environment so that I can write my own python programs to control it.

I have come across the following project: https://github.com/maxinbjohn/robotic_arm_driver

Could someone give me some advice on how to install it. The readme docs say "Select the 'USB ROBOTIC ARM' and build the kernel" but how can this be done as I don't know how to download and install the files using Bash (I'm from a windows background). Again, sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm trying to install it on Ubuntu OS.